# How can I solve this system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{align}
x+y(k^2-6)+z(4k+4)&=5k+3\\
-x+y(2k^2-6)+z(4k+4)&=6k+3
\end{align}$$

I must use matrices to find for which values of $k$ this system has:

1. exactly one solution,
2. infinitely-many solutions, and
3. no solution at all.

I tried solving it and think that: for $-1,2,-2$ the system has infinitely-many solutions; if $k$ is different from these, then the system will have only one solution; and there will never be a value of $k$ in which there will be no solution at all, but this turned out to be wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Three unknowns should have three equations...